# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence with Spring boot calling stored procedure

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, plsql

I am trying to call Oracle stored procedure from Spring boot Rest service. When I run the service locally from my pc and call it with Postman, I get expected results.

The problem is when I deploy my WAR file to Tomcat, and try to call it from Postman. I get ORA Fetch out of sequence error. Same thing happens when I try to call procedure from Oracle Toad client.

I would assume this is caused by something inside Oracle procedure so I posted the code below, althought I don't understand how it works when I run the service locally, but not when I deploy it on Tomcat server or call it directly from Ora client.

Procedure is rather simple with only one not so simple query. I checked query alone, and it gives expected results.
Debuging procedure showed that this is part of the code that is giving the error above (opening cursor for vStmt):

```
vStmt :='SELECT to_char(tt.date_time, ''dd.mm.yyyy'') date_time,
tt.bsc_name,
tt.bs_name,
tt.bs_site_id,
tt.cell_name,
tt.cell_id,
tt.tch_avail_channels_r,
tt.tch_avail_channels_r_min,
tt.tch_traff,
tt.ps_traffic,
tt.sdcch_avail_channels_r,
tt.sdcch_def_channels , 
kk.num_of_dropout_days FROM
 (SELECT  a.date_time,bsc_name ,
    bs_name,
    bs_site_id,
    cell_name,
    cell_id,
    tch_avail_channels_r,
    to_char(cell_downtime_mi, ''9990D99'') tch_avail_channels_r_min,
    tch_traff,
    a.ps_traffic,
    a.sdcch_avail_channels_r,
    a.sdcch_def_channels                                          
    FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day a 
    WHERE a.cell_downtime_mi  BETWEEN '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
    AND a.date_time BETWEEN  '''|| to_char(dStartTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' AND  '''|| to_char(dEndTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' '  || vOrderByString ||' ) tt,
    (SELECT cell_id, 
    count(cell_id) num_of_dropout_days 
    FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day a 
    WHERE a.cell_downtime_mi BETWEEN  '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
    AND a.date_time BETWEEN  '''|| to_char(dStartTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' AND  '''|| to_char(dEndTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' group by cell_id )  kk                                           
    WHERE tt.cell_id = kk.cell_id ' 
                    ;   
                              
     if vDaysInDropOut is not null then
       vStmt := vStmt || '  and kk.num_of_dropout_days  in ( ' || vDaysInDropOut  || ')';
                    end if;             
                                                                                    
                OPEN curCells FOR vStmt;
```

I did not post any Spring boot code, since I get this error with Ora Client too. Does any1 have any ideas why is this happening?

EDIT:

Here is the full procedure code. It should return cursor as out parameter:

```
procedure p_Get_Dropout_BS_2G(dStartTime in date, dEndTime in date, nDropTimeStart in number default 0.01, nDropTimeEnd in number default 25, curCells out SYS_REFCURSOR, vBSDrop in number default 0, vBSName varchar2 default null, vOrderBy varchar2 default 'DATE_TIME', vAscDesc varchar2 default 'ASC', vMessage in out varchar2, vDaysInDropOut in varchar2 default '' ) as

vEmesg                        varchar2(200);
dTime_start                 date;  
vStmt                         varchar2(2000);
vOrderByString              varchar2(400);
   
begin

execute immediate 'alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '',.''';

SELECT sysdate INTO dTime_start FROM dual;   
INSERT INTO eniq_log(message_txt, message_type, time_start, time_end) VALUES (vOrderBy,  'ERROR', dTime_start, sysdate);


if (upper(vOrderBy) = 'BS_NAME' ) then
    vOrderByString := 'ORDER BY ' || vOrderBy || ' ' || vAscDesc || ', date_time  ASC';
else
    vOrderByString := 'ORDER BY ' || vOrderBy || ' ' || vAscDesc;
end if;


if vBSDrop=0 then                            

vStmt :='SELECT to_char(tt.date_time, ''dd.mm.yyyy'') date_time,tt.bsc_name ,tt.bs_name,tt.bs_site_id,tt.cell_name,tt.cell_id,tt.tch_avail_channels_r,tt.tch_avail_channels_r_min,tt.tch_traff,tt.ps_traffic,tt.sdcch_avail_channels_r,tt.sdcch_def_channels , kk.num_of_dropout_days FROM (SELECT  a.date_time,bsc_name ,
bs_name,
bs_site_id,
cell_name,
cell_id,
tch_avail_channels_r,
to_char(cell_downtime_mi, ''9990D99'') tch_avail_channels_r_min,
tch_traff,
a.ps_traffic,
a.sdcch_avail_channels_r,
a.sdcch_def_channels                                          
FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day a 
WHERE a.cell_downtime_mi  BETWEEN '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
AND a.date_time BETWEEN  '''|| to_char(dStartTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' AND  '''|| to_char(dEndTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' '  || vOrderByString ||' ) tt,
(SELECT cell_id, 
count(cell_id) num_of_dropout_days 
FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day a 
WHERE a.cell_downtime_mi BETWEEN  '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
AND a.date_time BETWEEN  '''|| to_char(dStartTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' AND  '''|| to_char(dEndTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||''' group by cell_id )  kk                                           
WHERE tt.cell_id = kk.cell_id ';   

                
        if vDaysInDropOut is not null then
            vStmt := vStmt || '  and kk.num_of_dropout_days  in ( ' || vDaysInDropOut  || ')';
        end if;             
                                                                                  
        OPEN curCells FOR vStmt;
else
                                                      
vStmt := 'SELECT to_char(tt.date_time, ''dd.mm.yyyy'') date_time,
tt.bsc_name ,
tt.bs_name,
tt.bs_site_id,
tt.cell_name,
tt.cell_id,
tt.tch_avail_channels_r,
tt.tch_avail_channels_r_min,
tt.tch_traff,
tt.ps_traffic,
tt.sdcch_avail_channels_r,
tt.sdcch_def_channels , kk.num_of_dropout_days  
FROM 
    (SELECT date_time,                                       
       bsc_name ,
       bs_name,
       bs_site_id,
       cell_name,
       cell_id,
       tch_avail_channels_r,
       to_char(cell_downtime_mi, ''9990D99'') tch_avail_channels_r_min,
       tch_traff,
       a.ps_traffic,
       a.sdcch_avail_channels_r,
       a.sdcch_def_channels  
                            FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day a 
                            WHERE a.cell_downtime_mi  BETWEEN '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
                            AND a.date_time BETWEEN  '''|| to_char(dStartTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||'''  AND  '''|| to_char(dEndTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||'''
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day c 
                                                                WHERE c.cell_downtime_mi  BETWEEN '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
                                                                AND c.date_time =  a.date_time 
                                                                AND a.bs_site_id = c.bs_site_id
                                                                GROUP BY c.bs_site_id, c.bs_num_of_cells   
                                                                HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT c.cell_id) = c.bs_num_of_cells) '
                           ||vOrderByString ||' ) tt,
                           (SELECT 
                                        bs_site_id,
                                        cell_id,
                                        count(bs_site_id)  num_of_dropout_days                                    
                            FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day a 
                            WHERE a.cell_downtime_mi  BETWEEN '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
                            AND a.date_time BETWEEN  '''|| to_char(dStartTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||'''  AND  '''|| to_char(dEndTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||'''
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM eniq_2g_bs_dropouts_day c 
                                                                WHERE c.cell_downtime_mi  BETWEEN '|| to_char(nDropTimeStart, '9990.9999') ||' AND '|| to_char(nDropTimeEnd,  '9990.9999') ||' 
                                                                AND c.date_time =  a.date_time 
                                                                AND a.bs_site_id = c.bs_site_id
                                                                GROUP BY c.bs_site_id, c.bs_num_of_cells   
                                                                HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT c.cell_id) = c.bs_num_of_cells) group by bs_site_id, cell_id)  kk                                           
            WHERE tt.cell_id = kk.cell_id '  ;
            
            if vDaysInDropOut is not null then
                vStmt := vStmt || '  and kk.num_of_dropout_days  in ( ' || vDaysInDropOut  || ')';
            end if;                               
            OPEN curCells FOR vStmt;
end if;


vMessage := 'OK';

EXCEPTION
    when OTHERS then 
                     vEmesg := 'ERROR: ENIQ.p_Get_Dropout_BS_2G // '  ||  SUBSTR(sqlerrm, 1, 70) || ' // TRACE ERROR: '|| DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE();
                    INSERT INTO eniq_log(message_txt, message_type, time_start, time_end) VALUES (vEmesg,  'ERROR', dTime_start, sysdate);   
                    COMMIT;     
                    vMessage := 'ERROR: ENIQ.p_Get_Dropout_BS'; 
end p_Get_Dropout_BS_2G;
```

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough to be able to help you. The problem here is not likely to be the structure of the query, but how the query and the cursor is used, and you have provided very few details on this. Please include the rest of the procedure in your question.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Posted full procedure above.

Comment: There are a few problems I can see. Firstly, do not concatenate values into your queries, as that leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. Secondly, you are comparing dates as strings, which will give you incorrect results. Your code will compare `05.09.2022` as between `01.01.2022` and `31.01.2022`, because this is true as strings but not as dates in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`. Thirdly, you are using `COMMIT` statements in a procedure intended only to retrieve data. Create a separate logging proc which uses an autonomous transaction, writes to your log table and commits, and call that.

Comment: However the single biggest problem is that these queries are large, and nobody will go to the effort of creating all of the tables you are using and figuring out what data they need to insert into all of them. The way you deal with this problem is to cut down your queries to the absolute minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Take out some bits of your queries, or your procedure code. If you still get the same error, take out more, but if the error goes away, put back what you took out and try taking out something else instead. Perhaps by doing this you'll find your problem by yourself.

Comment: WHEN OTHERS... doing a commit??? very odd.

Comment: I did break the query bits by bits and got it working...but unfortunately I cant change this procedure since it was not written by me, and I only have permission to call it. So Ill have to do a workaround. Was curious about this error since it can be tied to few things acording to Google, thus wanted to ask some ideas about it, and possible causes.